# Probability that a single coin generates a certain number of heads when tossing multiple coins

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm having trouble with the following problem

> If you toss 1000 fair coins 10 times, what is the probability that **some** coin will get 10 heads?

I have tried to use the binomial distribution, but I think I'm missing something since we have multiple coins.

Comment: this is a duplicate questions for any mods out there. not sure why it didn't show up in my suggestions when making the problem

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274633/if-you-toss-1000-fair-coins-10-times-each-what-is-the-probability-the-some?rq=1

Comment: tried deleting this question, but it won't let me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The probability that a coin will get $10$ heads is...

So the probability that a coin will not get $10$ heads is...

So the probability that all $1000$ coins will not get $10$ heads is...

So the probability that some of the $1000$ coins will get $10$ heads is...

---

**Edit**:

> $2^{-10}$, $1-2^{-10}$, $(1-2^{-10})^{1000}$, $1-(1-2^{-10})^{1000}$

Comment: I believe the answer to the first question is 0.000976 (i.e. probability one coin tossed 10 times will give 10 heads) and I know how to take the complement, but for multiple coins would you just multiply the first probability by 1000?? This doesn't seem right since you could eventually get an answer > 1.0

Comment: multiplying by $1000$ is incorrect. I have edited.